# WPF4 cannot find storyboard from code

Tags: c#, animation, storyboard

for some reason I can't access my Storyboard from code.

```
<Window x:Class="test.Overlay"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="Overlay" Height="300" Width="300" WindowState="Maximized">
<Window.Resources>
    <Storyboard x:Key="lightFadeToBlack">
        <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Opacity)" Storyboard.TargetName="lightRec">
            <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.4" Value="1"/>
        </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
    </Storyboard>
    <Storyboard x:Key="lightFadeToMovie">
        <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Opacity)" Storyboard.TargetName="lightRec">
            <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.4" Value="0"/>
        </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
    </Storyboard>
</Window.Resources>
```

...

I should be able to start it with c# using lightFadeToBlack.Begin(); but lightFadeToBlack cannot be found.

Comment: Have you tried specifying `x:Name="lightFaceToMovie"`?

Comment: makes no difference for me :(

Comment: What's your code? Do you call it before `InitializeComponent()`?

Comment: no. also this shouldnt make a diffrence because not even intellisense finds it.

Comment: IntelliSense cannot find resources in <Resources> section. Please post your code that you use to reference that Storyboard. And also let us know where you have put it.